# Self-Organizing Time Map

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis, self-organizing-maps

Is there an implementation of the Self Organizing Time Map in any language available? (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231212005759)

I know the Kohonen package for R, but it has the basic implementation and not the SOTM, or any other variant.

Are these available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I've read that paper before and I think that it's from the research that Sarlin did for his PhD research. I've not seen code for it online, but you might try to contact him directly. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Sarlin